# Is the mBJ functional reliable for band structure calculations in VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, functional

I am currently looking at band structure mainly for a few magnetic compounds. Due to having a large super-cell my calculations have not converged with the HSE06 functional. So I looked at what else is possible, and I came accross a couple of papers (for example [this one](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-020-00360-0)) which were comparing different functionals. According to them, HSE06 and mBJ are the most reliable functionals for band Structure calculations.

[This](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/154/how-trustworthy-is-the-tran-blaha-modified-becke-johnson-potential-and-how-does) post and [this post](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/154/5) talk about how the TBmBJ functional is not reliable and I am wondering if the same thing can be said for mBJ.

Answer (score 1):

## mBJ vs TBmBJ

Let's ask ourselves what the difference is between mBJ and TBmBJ.    A quite recent paper, published in 2020 and with already 37 citations on Google Scholar, is [this one](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.9b01147) which says:

> "The modified Becke-Johnson exchange-correlation potential was proposed by Tran and Blaha in 2009."

Therefore the answers to:[How trustworthy is the Tran-Blaha modified Becke-Johnson potential and how does it perform across basis sets?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/154/5) technically can apply to your question. Similarly for the thread that you found yourself: [How trustworthy is the Tran-Blaha modified Becke-Johnson potential and how does it perform across basis sets?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/154/how-trustworthy-is-the-tran-blaha-modified-becke-johnson-potential-and-how-does)

## Two more clarifications

##### Potential vs functional

mBJ is usually referred as a "potential" rather than as a "functional", and the reliability of it has been explained in detail in Anubab Haldar's answer to the following question: [How does the mBJ potential give an accurate band gap as compared to LDA and GGA?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/836/5)

##### mBJ vs HSE06

You have said that you found several papers that said that HSE06 and mBJ are the two most reliable out of everything, and yet your next sentence asks if mBJ is reliable, even though you already said that you can't use HSE06, and that mBJ is the second best according to your literature search. This indicates that despite all the other answers, your only option (as you have presented the options) is to use mBJ.